# Is it possible to use XML from an external website?

Tags: php, javascript, xml, xslt

I have researched this topic for months now with no success. Many posts say it is possible but I have yet been able to get it to work.

Here is the issue, we are using a resource that provides a data file in XML. It can be found at the following URL: http://www.idexonline.com/image_portal/Home/Graph/Base/IDEXOnlineDiamondIndex.xml

I want to insert this data into an existing webpage.

I've tried accessing this data using XSL, or XML include and a variety of other techniques with no luck.

I am currently using PHP on this site. But, I am open to the method, it can use JavaScript or other techniques! HELP!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read/display XML using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1081627/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<?php

$file  = 'http://www.idexonline.com';
$file .= '/image_portal/Home/Graph/Base/IDEXOnlineDiamondIndex.xml';

$xml = file_get_contents($file);

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML($xml);
$domXPath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);

$xPath = '/root/index';
$index = $domXPath->evaluate("string($xPath)");

$xPath = '/root/change';
$change = $domXPath->evaluate("string($xPath)");
$change = number_format(round($change, 2), 2);

echo "The index is '$index' and the change is '$change'";
```

The output was this at the time:

> The index is '139.04' and the change is '0.00'

Comment: That seems to work pretty good. Do you know if there is a way to round the Change number to one or two decimals?

Comment: Jim, I've added a line to round the change to and format as two decimals.  However, based on what I've seen of the value of the change for the last couple of days, I think you'll want a higher precision for in order for the value of change to have any meaning.  With such tiny numbers, pretty much everything is going to round to zero. Without knowing what sort of index/change your data are from, it's hard to say what precision you should use.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This works perfectly! You rock

Comment: I will check with the client. On their own website they usually round to 2 decimals and indicate whether the change was positive or negative. Thanks again

Comment: I just checked your code with 3 decimals and it displays -0.001. I think that's perfect.

Comment: Well, if you're rounding to three decimals and the value of change is less than -0.0005, it will still remove the negative sign (since anything less than -0.0005 rounded to three decimals is exactly zero.)  If you like my response, will you accept it as your answer?

Comment: It actually displayed -0.001. For this industry, a change smaller than that is effectively zero. You definitely created a great answer. I'm sure there are other ways to do it too, but this works for me. Although I'd love to be able to solve it natively in XML, too.

Answer (score 1):

If the site didn't block you, you can get the data like below.

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.idexonline.com/image_portal/Home/Graph/Base/IDEXOnlineDiamondIndex.xml');
 print_r($xml);
```

Comment: I don't see how this works. Can you supply the complete code? Did you save this as XML, HTML or something else?

Comment: @JimMaivald This is the complete code for getting the data. http://codepad.viper-7.com/3EDmMH

Comment: @JimMaivald Just read the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: I appreciate your help on this question. But your replies ignore the basic tenor of it. I was trying a variety of techniques. Your code is not complete. To be complete you would have to enter it thusly: <?php  $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.idexonline.com/image_portal/Home/Graph/Base/IDEXOnlineDiamondIndex.xml');
 print_r($xml); ?>

Comment: @JimMaivald I'm sorry, I just thought you know that is just php code :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about the correct solution for this. But AFAIK accessing data from another location requires a cross domain access policy on the remote machine. [Wikipedia's take on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: The solutions using PHP above both work beautifully. The solution suggesting XSL, I have not gotten to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

**This XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pUrl" select=
 "'http://www.idexonline.com/image_portal/Home/Graph/Base/IDEXOnlineDiamondIndex.xml'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <textarea>
       <xsl:copy-of select="document($pUrl)"/>
     </textarea>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document, produces**:

```
<textarea>
   <root>
      <index>139.09</index>
      <change>-0.00036470</change>
   </root>
</textarea>
```

Comment: I tried applying your XSL using:
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xmlfeedtest.xsl" ?>
It didn't work for me. Were you using a different method?

Comment: @JimMaivald: [Re: Were you using a different method?] Of course, I never use the browser to initiate an XML transformation. One can initiate a transformation from code (JS, C#, Java,..., etc.), using a command-line utility (nearly ever XSLT processor comes with such), or from an XSLT IDE.

Comment: @JimMaivald: It is quite possible that the browser initiates the XSLT processor in a mode, in which the `document()` function is disabled/forbidden.